# sonata user-bundle symfony 3.4 problem installation with Flex

Tags: sonata, symfony-3.4, sonata-user-bundle, symfony-flex

I have a problem with the installation of sonata-project/user-bundle on a **Symfony 3.4** project using **Symfony Flex**.

After the installation, during the execution of the script cache:clear, this one returned KO and the message is:

```
The child node "db_driver" at path "fos_user" must be configured.
```

Does someone have an idea to fix this problem?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

Because Sonata User is built on top of FOS User you have to also configure the FOS bundle.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#step-5-configure-the-fosuserbundle

Step 5 here will fix your problem.

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: "%mailer_user%"
        sender_name: "%mailer_user%"
```